# Movesense data logger for ECG

Tags: logging, movesense

Right now I’m trying to write ECG data to the logbook using my own app. But, every time I try to read the logs, I get an internal server error as response. Here is an example of this error.

```
E/Komposti: Logbook::getData: Failed to read data.
    [SDS RESPONSE] type: GET status: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR header: {"TaskId": 41, "Uri": "suunto://MDS/Logbook/192630002431/ById/2/Data", "Content-Length": 0, "Reason": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", "Status": 500} error: Failed to read data
```

Before I wrote this issue, I also tried to fetch the log data with the “DataLoggerSample” app, provided by your company. It works fine if I log “/Meas/Acc/13”, in my own app, and also with the DataLoggerSample app, but if I change the logger config to “/Meas/ECG/125/” or “/Meas/ECG/128/”, the Movesense sensor answers with: STATUS 500 - INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

The following JSON, shows the logger configuration for ECG:

```
{
    "config": {
        "dataEntries": {
            "dataEntry": [
                {
                    "path": "/Meas/ECG/125"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "config": {
        "dataEntries": {
            "dataEntry": [
                {
                    "path": "/Meas/Acc/13"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t know if I’m missing something, but I already spent several hours but haven’t found anything. Is the “config” object in the JSON needed? In the documentation of the datalogger, the “config” object is not described, but it works well with the Acc.
Is there a trick, to get it to work?

My setup is:

- Sensor 1 - SW version: 1.9.4
- Sensor 2 - SW version: 1.9.0
- Models: OP174
- MDS lib version: 1.44.0

‌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not able to save ECG is that Movesense framework <=1.9.x does not support it. The DataLogger & Logbook features needed to support this have been added in the coming 2.0 release. The actual release is still not out (thanks to COVID-19) but the [2.0 pre-release is available](http://movesense.com/docs/esw2preview/intro/).

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*